# Power Query : Fiscal Month Day Number WorkingDay

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I have a simple fiscal calendar that has this structure:

```
Date    Fiscal Month    Fiscal MonthDays    IsWorkingDay
01.01.2021  12  40  FALSE
02.01.2021  12  41  FALSE
03.01.2021  12  42  FALSE
04.01.2021  1   1   TRUE
05.01.2021  1   2   TRUE
06.01.2021  1   3   TRUE
07.01.2021  1   4   TRUE
08.01.2021  1   5   TRUE
09.01.2021  1   6   FALSE
10.01.2021  1   7   FALSE
```

I have a column "Fiscal MonthDays" that shows me the sequential Day Number, regardless if it is a working day or not. Now I would like to add a column with the day number just for working dayys.

How would you do this?

Comment: what is the highest day number? 5? The number of days in the year?

Comment: The highest number is 42 for a December/ 53 week year where fiscal month December has 6 weeks instead of 5

Answer (score 0):

See if this works for you

Add index

Filter for Working Days

Group on Fiscal Month (you may want to add Fiscal Year as well) and add 2nd index. Expand

Merge back into original table

Note that WorkingDayNumber from any partial month at the start of the table will have the wrong numbers. You might want to filter out any rows where the FiscalMonth does not have a 1 in the FiscalMonthDays column as well. Not accounted for here

[image]

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Date", type date}}),
#"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Changed Type", "Index", 0, 1),

//filter for WorkingDay, Group, Add index based on Fiscal Month
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Added Index", each ([IsWorkingDay] = true)),
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Filtered Rows", {"Fiscal Month"}, {{"Count", each Table.AddIndexColumn(_, "Index2", 1, 1), type table}}),
#"Expanded Count" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Count", {"Index", "Index2"}, {"Index", "Index2"}),

//Merge back to original table
#"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Added Index",{"Index"},#"Expanded Count",{"Index"},"Table2",JoinKind.LeftOuter),
#"Expanded Table2" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "Table2", {"Index2"}, {"WorkingDaysNumber"}),
#"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Expanded Table2",{{"Index", Order.Ascending}}),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Sorted Rows",{"Index"})
in #"Removed Columns"
```

Answer (score 0):

Slightly different way (assuming you use data for single year, otherwise you should firstly create a column for unique months (format like YYYY_MM) and then group the table by it, instead of Fiscal Month column):

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Data"]}[Content],
    group = Table.Group(Source, {"Fiscal Month","IsWorkingDay"}, {"temp", each _}),
    replace = Table.ReplaceValue(group,each [IsWorkingDay],"TRUE",(a,b,c)=>if b=c then Table.AddIndexColumn(a,"i",1) else a,{"temp"}),
    final = Table.Combine(replace[temp])
in
    final
```